# How to Convert Date and Time String into Different format?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I am saving date and time in a single column i.e 2015-04-15 13:22:58 and I want to show this time and date in this format: 15th April 2015, 1:22 pm.
I have used this code:

```
$dt = '2015-04-15 13:22:58';
echo date("jS F Y", strtotime($dt));
```

and it shows only date (15th April 2015). How can I fetch time along with date?? Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$dt = '2015-04-15 13:22:58';

echo date("jS F Y h:i a", strtotime($dt)); 
//Result is 15th April 2015 01:22 pm

echo date("jS F Y g:i a", strtotime($dt)); 
// Result is 15th April 2015 1:22 pm
```

Answer (score 1):

change `"jS F Y"` to `"js F Y g:i a"`. That will output the time in your desired format as well as the date.

```
$dt = '2015-04-15 13:22:58';
echo date("jS F Y g:i a", strtotime($dt));
```

Output:

```
15th April 2015 1:22 pm
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to format date time in php, you can use `date_format` like this.

```
echo date_format(strtotime($dt), "jS F Y g:i A");
```